# Hibernate - get Object version from db

Tags: java, hibernate

There is scenario in my application:
1. I get objects from database:

```
hql = "some hql query";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
return query.list();
```

2. User makes changes on this object.
3. User is not pleased with changes and wants to reload DB version of objects. (kind of 'abort edit' action)

This is where I hit the wall. When I try to get objects second time hibernate gives me references to the same objects that are already in memory - I can tell that by comparison objects id in debug mode. But these objects in memory are changed in comparison to DB version.
How could I force hibernate to read object from DB instead of giving me reference to already changed version in memory?

Comment: Have you tried session.clear(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java Persistence 2.0 specification:

> **3.2.5 Refreshing an Entity Instance**
>
> The state of a managed entity instance is refreshed from the database by invoking the `refresh` method
>   on it or by cascading the refresh operation.